# How to export data from Odoo to RStudio

Tags: r, odoo

My company has just started using Odoo services and I'm also quite new to it and I've seen that it uses alot of Python and Javascript (which im not too familiar with). I use RStudio for a lot of my data gathering and analysis.

Is there a way to automatically get data from Odoo through api's or some sort into RStudio in order to analyze it and do whatever i need to do?

At the moment I'm just manually exporting the data from odoo into a csv and then importing that into R. is there a better and more automatic way?

Comment: I believe there is a REST API module for Odoo which may offer the service you need.

Comment: @PGSA would you happen to know where i can find the documentation for that?

Comment: I'm afraid not - I just googled for similar issues and it came up.

Comment: You can try using query directly to its database.

Comment: @holydragon do you mind explaining this a little bit further? bit confused by what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if RStudio can actually fetch data from a database, but I saw [one of the guides](https://medium.com/geekculture/a-simple-guide-on-connecting-rstudio-to-a-postgresql-database-9e35ccdc08be) successfully did it.

If that is really the case, you can get the data from Odoo's database (most likely PostgreSQL) by writing query directly to the database.